# Show that $x+y\geq x^\alpha y^{1-\alpha}$

Tags: inequality

Is it possible to show that $$x+y\geq x^\alpha y^{1-\alpha}$$ for $\alpha \in(0,1]$ and $x,y\in[0,\infty)$?

I tried to manipulate it algebraically, but it does not give me any anything. Equivalently, we need to show that
$$x^\alpha - y^\alpha \leq xy^{\alpha - 1}$$

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Do *you* have any thoughts on how to prove it?

Comment: Your equivalency is incorrect. Take $x = y = 1$ and $\alpha = 1$ you'd get $2 \leq 1$ wich is incorrect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$x+y\geqslant\max\{x,y\}=\max\{x,y\}^\alpha\max\{x,y\}^{1-\alpha}\geqslant x^\alpha y^{1-\alpha}$$

Comment: That was very clever!

Comment: Beautiful! +1$ $

Answer (score 3):

If $y = 0$ this is obvious for any $x \geq 0$.

If $y \neq 0$ this is equivalent to:

$$\frac{x}{y} + 1 \geq \frac{x^\alpha}{y^\alpha}$$

Taking $z = \frac{x}{y}$ we need to prove that

$$z+1\geq z^\alpha$$

For $\alpha\in (0,1]$ and $z\geq 0$.

Now we have two cases: $z \geq 1$ and $0\leq z < 1$.

In the first case, the function $z^t$ is increasing so $z^\alpha \leq z^1$ since $\alpha \leq 1$ so $z^\alpha \leq 1 + z$.

In the second case, the function $z^t$ is decreasing so $z^\alpha < z^0 = 1$ since $\alpha > 0$ so $z^\alpha < 1 + z$